# Help needed adding echo to single line of PHP script

Tags: php, variables, echo

I am pretty much a new newbie when it comes to PHP, and have a problem that I need to solve, for a website that has to go live tomorrow.

Basically I have been using a javascript upload script called 'uploadify' which had an option for the upload folder which was added to the script in the form:

```
'folder'    : '/songs/<?php echo $_SESSION["name"];?>',
```

I added the php echo to return the username from a PHP login, so it gets added to the path to the upload folder (each user has their own subfolder for uploading to).

With the new version of the uploadify script, the folder option has been moved to a separate PHP file where it is now in the form:

```
$targetFolder = '/songs/';
```

I need to find a way of adding the username variable to this line.  I have tried using echo in various ways, and googled about, but it has stumped me, simple as it may be.

If anyone could let me know how I construct this line I'd be very grateful.  Time is of the essence, as they say...

Thanks,

Nick

I thought I'd include all of the php involved in case this illuminates why the session var isn't available to uploadify.php.

First there is this at the top of the index.php page:

```
<?
require("log.php");
?>
```

Which triggers log.php:

```
<?
session_name("MyLogin");
session_start();

if($_GET['action'] == "login") {
$conn = mysql_connect("","",""); // your MySQL connection data
$db = mysql_select_db(""); //put your database name in here 
$name = $_POST['user'];
$q_user = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE login='$name'");

if(mysql_num_rows($q_user) == 1) {

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE login='$name'");
$data = mysql_fetch_array($query);
if($_POST['pwd'] == $data['password']) { 
$_SESSION["name"] = $name;
header("Location: http://monthlymixup.com/index.php"); // success page. put the URL you want 
exit;
} else {
header("Location: login.php?login=failed&cause=".urlencode('Wrong Password'));
exit;
}
} else {
header("Location: login.php?login=failed&cause=".urlencode('Invalid User'));
exit;
}
}

// if the session is not registered
if(session_is_registered("name") == false) {
header("Location: login.php");
}

?>
```

(I have removed MySql info from this)

This then calls the login.php, which has this php at the top (followed by the html for the form):

```
<?
session_name("MyLogin");
session_start();
session_destroy();

if($_GET['login'] == "failed") {
print $_GET['cause'];
}
?>
```

which includes session_destroy();.  Which I thought may be causing the problem, but I deleted this line, and the session var isn't passed to uploadify.php (and why would it be available to index.php it it is destroyed here?).  uploadify.php currently looks like this:

```
<?php

session_start()

print_r($_SESSION);

$targetFolder = '/songs/' . $_SESSION['name']; // Relative to the root

if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
    $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $targetFolder;
    $targetFile = rtrim($targetPath,'/') .'/'. $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];

    // Validate the file type
    $fileTypes = array('m4a','mp3','flac','ogg'); // File extensions
    $fileParts = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);

    if (in_array($fileParts['extension'],$fileTypes)) {
        move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
        echo '1';
    } else {
        echo 'Invalid file type.';
    }
}
?>
```

The uploadify.php is referred to in jquery.uploadify.js.  I think these are all the lines that are relevant:

```
uploader : 'uploadify.php',

upload_url  : settings.uploader,

case 'uploader':
                            swfuploadify.setUploadURL(settingValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

Could it be this simple?

```
$targetFolder = '/songs/' . $_SESSION['name'];
```

Comment: It could be this simple, but for some reason I don't have the session var to work with on uploadify.php. please see my responses above and below

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you still have the session var to work with...

```
$targetFolder = '/songs/' . $_SESSION['name'];
```

Comment: thanks.  for some reason I don't seem to have a session var to work with.  I have found a session_destroy() in the login.php, but wonder why the session would still be available to the index.php page if it has been destroyed. And even when I remove this line from login.php, the session var still isn't available to uploadify.php.

Comment: How are you landing on uploadify.php? A form submit I assume? If that is the case you could add a hidden field with the username and pass it to uploadify.php via POST.
`$targetFolder = '/songs/' . $_POST['user_path'];`

Comment: `<input type="hidden" name="user_path" value="<?=$_SESSION['name']?>" />`
Since you said you have access to the session on the main page, that should work.

Comment: I am not sure how I am landing on uploadify.php.  It is simply referred to in jquery.uploadify.js.  I have now included all the php from the various pages above, in case this is illuminating.

Comment: `session_name("MyLogin");` is missing from the top of uploadify.php, that could be your problem. And I would probably remove the `session_destroy()` also, at least for now. If anything it should be be present on index.php, once the user has successfully logged in.

Comment: Thanks.  The lack of session_name was indeed the issue for getting the session var to work with uploadify.php.  Now when I add `print_r($_SESSION);` to uploadify.php, I see `Array ( [name] => nick )`.  However I have tried amending the `$targetfolder` line in all three ways suggested on this page, i.e. `$targetFolder = '/songs/' . $_SESSION['name'];``$targetFolder = "/songs/{$_SESSION['name']}";`  and  `$targetFolder = '/songs/' . $_SESSION['name'] . '/';` and with all three methods, the uploaded songs get written to the parent directory 'songs' and not the username directory

Comment: Echo out $targetFolder. It should be "/songs/nick/" (with or without the trailing slash, whatever works). If it is (which it should be), that isn't your problem. Does the directory exist? If you hadn't added any code to create a directory that doesn't exist, that would be a problem.

Comment: Yes, when I echo out $targetFolder I am seeing "/songs/nick/" or "/songs/nick" depending on which version of the script I am using.  The directory does exist, with correct permissions, and if I manually enter "/songs/nick", i.e. `$targetFolder = '/songs/nick'` then files are uploaded to the correct directory.  So it is rather strange that it doesn't work with the var.

Comment: Wow, I'm sorry, I'm completely stumped now. If `$targetFolder` echo's the exact same thing as you are inputing with `$targetFoldder = 'songs/nick'`, then I am at a total loss. The only other inconsistency I can see between any of the files is that you used `["name"]` in log.php and `['name']` in uploadify.php (double/single quotes). I seriously doubt that is a problem, but when all else fails... :/

Comment: yes, it's a mystery, and, unfortunately one that is integral to my whole website!, so I will persevere and try to get to the bottom of it.  it's the same issue with double or single quotes, as you suspected. thanks for your help anyway.  It would seem I am just one step away from a functional website now

Answer (score 0):

```
$targetFolder = "/songs/{$_SESSION['name']}";
```

EDIT: Your issue is [`session_name`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php).  If you *ever* use that (which is not usually necessary), "you need to call session_name() for every request (and before session_start() or session_register() are called)."

Comment: Thanks.  The lack of session_name was indeed the issue for getting the session var to work with uploadify.php.  Now when I add `print_r($_SESSION);` to uploadify.php, I see `Array ( [name] => nick )`.  However I have tried amending the `$targetfolder` line in all three ways suggested on this page, i.e. `$targetFolder = '/songs/' . $_SESSION['name'];``$targetFolder = "/songs/{$_SESSION['name']}";`  and  `$targetFolder = '/songs/' . $_SESSION['name'] . '/';` and with all three methods, the uploaded songs get written to the parent directory 'songs' and not the username directory

Answer (score 0):

## Concatenation

Just use concatenation....

```
$targetFolder = '/songs/' . $_SESSION['name'];
```

Should you need a trailing slash (since it was working before without It i dont think you do), use :

```
$targetFolder = '/songs/' . $_SESSION['name'] . '/';
```

When you are within a PHP script, adding variables to the string of another variable is trivial - using the "." dot operator, you can concatenate or join strings.

### Further

I would also check if the session name variable exists, and perhaps cancel out or set a default if it doesnt. perhaps

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['name'])) 
  do { $_SESSION['name'] = microtime(); } while(!file_exists('songs/'.$_SESSION['name']));
```

This will actively find a new folder for that file and it will not overwrite existing folders.

#### Links

[A simple guide here](http://phphowto.blogspot.com/2006/12/concatenate-strings.html)

[PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

**As mentioned above**, an alternative is to use double quotes and the "{}" to achieve the same result. What you'll find is that using double quotes over single quotes can be very marginally slower because the string parser will check to see if you've included any variables and 'expand' them out to their value. Both syntaxes are acceptable.

### Session Problem

Here's what I normally do to transfer the session ID

```
$('#file_upload').uploadify({

            'uploader':  '/prototype/site/assets/template/swf/uploadify.swf',
                'script':    '/prototype/jobs/filemanager/upload',
                'cancelImg': '/prototype/site/assets/template/images/cancel.png',
                'auto': true,
                'multi': false,
                'fileDesc': 'Portable Document Format *.pdf',
                'fileExt': '*.pdf',
                'buttonText':'Upload',
                'onComplete': load_list,
                'scriptAccess':'always',
                'checkScript':'/jobs/filemanager/check',
                'scriptData': {'session_id':'<?php echo session_id()?>'},
                'queueID':'queue'
            });
```

See that script data? I basically output the session id and then pass that onto the uploadify.php (well my example doesn't use uploadify.php, that's contained in a class but it's the same thing)

Comment: Wow, thanks for all these responses, and so quickly.  I have tried implementing a few of them and none work, which I presume means that I don't still have the session var to work with.  It is still available on the main page though, and worked before with the echo code.

Comment: I recommend placing a `session_start();` at the very top of the page with the `$targetFolder` variable. session start needs to occur before anything is sent to the browser.

Comment: Thanks Jason.  I added a session_start();, and then a print_r($_SESSION); but the session var still isn't available to the uploadify.php page

Comment: I'm using uploadify as well, i'll have to test this out for you. The question is though, is your browser submitting the session cookie over to that page. see my answer for more info

Comment: Hi Jason.  Not sure if you are following the discussion above I have been having with zdkroot.  Adding session_name("MyLogin"); meant that the session var is now available to the page, and echoing out $targetFolder returned the correct path: '/songs/nick', but the uploads still go to the parent directory 'songs', when using `$targetFolder = '/songs/' . $_SESSION['name'];`.  Manually entering `$targetFolder = '/songs/nick';` works fine, which is rather mystifying.

Answer (score -1):

You're looking for a [concatenation operator ('.')](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php):

```
$targetFolder = '/songs/'.$_SESSION["name"].'/';
```

Comment: If you're going to add a `/`, you should explain why.

Comment: Since the original /songs/ folder has a / as well; might make a difference, depending how the script uses it. And if you're going to downvote an answer that's correct, you should explain why.

Answer (score -2):

So long as the user name is being stored in a session variable make sure that whatever script $targetFolder resides in has the session started (session_start()) and change that line to the following:

```
$targetFolder= "/songs/".$_SESSION['name'].'/';
```

If $_SESSION['name'] = "foo" your path would now be /songs/foo/.

Comment: That is intentional.  The original path includes a '/' at the end, the new one should as well.

Comment: @Matthew: Look at the path in the original post, it clearly does: "/songs/" -- therefore the next level down would be "/songs/user/" -- I don't see how you can argue this.

Comment: @Nicholas, There's a `/` after songs, but there's none after `$_SESSION['name']`.  Where do you think one is being output *after* `$_SESSION['name']` in the original?  `/songs/username` is a perfectly valid absolute path.

Comment: @Matthew: There is in the default path "/songs/" and there *should* be (whether his "echo statement" reflected that or not) in the subdirectory portion as well. The path should be /dir/subdir/ so that files would then be uploaded into /dir/subdir/file.  I don't see how this is up for debate?  There wasn't one in the original I am not debating that but I think (and it is correct) that one should have been there.

Comment: @Matthew: I am also curious as to why you voted down my post yet none of the other which include the trailing '/' -- there is no way you can argue that including the '/' is incorrect.  While it may be unnecessary it most certainly isn't wrong.

Comment: @Nicholas, he specifically said he's "been using" the former one, which means the `/` is unneeded.  Another reason for the downvote is that you're the only one who said "The original path includes a '/' at the end", which is wrong.

Comment: @Matthew: By original path I am referring to the default value for the variable he is trying to modify ($targetFolder) which as he stated was "/songs/" -- and yes that does have a trailing '/'.  I think that your down vote in this case is completely unwarranted.

Comment: I seem to have started something here!  As I mentioned in my response to Jason, none of these methods work for me, which I presume means that the session var isn't available to the uploadify.php page.  How do I make it available?

Comment: @Nick: Assuming it is still being set somewhere adding a call to session_start() in the uploadify.php script (before you reference the $_SESSION variable) should do the trick.  To test and see if the variable is set you can add a print_r($_SESSION); after your call to session_start().  I wouldn't say you started anything but Matthew certainly seems to have something against me, not sure why.  Just for the record Nick, having a trailing '/' in your path would still function properly, correct?

Comment: thanks, I added a print_r($_SESSION); to the main page, and that showed Array ( [name] => nick ).  But then I added it to uploadify.php, after a session_start(), and saw nothing on the webpage (just a blank page).

Comment: @Nick: Assuming you added the call to session_start() at the very top of the uploadify.php script and referred to the variable after that call you should be in good shape.  What if you add the call to session_start() on the 1st line of uploadify.php then do a print_r(_$SESSION); in that script.  Does the value still show up?

Comment: Nicholas, thanks for persevering with me. I am new to php, so perhaps I am doing something obviously wrong. I have now added the uploadify.php in its entirety to my original post.  All I know is that when I add the print_r(_$SESSION); to my index.php, which is where I call the uploadify script and where it worked before with the echo line, I see Array ( [name] => nick ) in the top of my browser window.  When I try to browse to uploadify.php I see nothing.

Comment: @Nick: I assume all you see is a white screen when you load uploadify.php which I believe is because you are missing a ';' after the call to session_start().  Try adding that and seeing what happens.

Comment: oops.  yes, now I see Array ( ), meaning that the session var isn't carrying across, so the call to session_start() isn't doing its job.

Comment: @Nick: It must get set and then destroyed/unset elsewhere then. Since it shows up in your index (which I presume the user is redirected to after logging in) it is definitely getting set properly.  Can you include a snippet of your index file or just look over it to ensure that there isn't a call to session_destroy() or unset($_SESSION['name']) ?

Comment: Yes, the user is redirected to the index page, and the session name is getting set correctly, because it worked with the echo $_SESSION["name"] with the old version of the uploadify script on the index page.  I searched for 'session' on the index page and the only times it turns up is in a small script at the top of the page which creates a directory for the user, and where there is no mention of destroying or unsetting, just creating directories.

Comment: I just found this at the top of the login.php: `<?
session_name("MyLogin");
session_start();
session_destroy();

if($_GET['login'] == "failed") {
print $_GET['cause'];
}
?>`  which seems relevant, but if it is getting destroyed at the login page, why would it be available for the index page?

Comment: I deleted the session_destroy(); line in login.php, in case it was the problem, but still no username in the array on uploadify.php

Comment: One more piece of information.  I created a dummy php file with just this code: `<?php

session_start();

print_r($_SESSION);

?>` on the same domain, and still just got the Array ().  Am I right in thinking that the user login should be stored on the server until it is either destroyed or the user ends the session?

Comment: @Nick: `Am I right in thinking that the user login should be stored on the server until it is either destroyed or the user ends the session?`

Yes, you are correct. All session variables will be stored on the server until the session is terminated.

Comment: @Nicholas @Unsigned Code Labs @Matthew @Alec @jnpcl @Jason  I have now included all the php from the various pages involved in my original post in case this is illuminating as to why the session var isn't available to the uploadify.php page

Comment: @Nicholas @Unsigned Code Labs @Alec @jnpcl @Jason  Thanks.  The lack of session_name was the issue for getting the session var to work with uploadify.php.  Now when I see `Array ( [name] => nick )` at the top of uploadify.php.  However I have tried amending the `$targetfolder` line in all 3 ways suggested, i.e. `$targetFolder = '/songs/' . $_SESSION['name'];``$targetFolder = "/songs/{$_SESSION['name']}";`  and  `$targetFolder = '/songs/' . $_SESSION['name'] . '/';` and with all three methods, the uploaded songs get written to the parent directory 'songs' and not the username directory

Comment: @Nick: Apparently the login value from the session isn't being carried over, in your login you could store the name in $_GET['user'] ($_GET['user'] = $_SESSION['name']) then pass that variable to both index and the uploadify script.  That way you would do something like url.com/Uploadify?user=Foo and the path would be: $targetFolder='/songs/'.$_GET['user']; (without the slash at the end) or $targetFolder='/songs/'.$_GET['user'].'/'; (with slash)